# Sticky Sidebar After Hidden Element Revealed

Tags: jquery, html, css, sidebar, sticky

I'm looking for sticky sidebar that does something specific and I'm not even sure how to word my queries/if anything like this exists.

I want to have a sticky call to action in the sidebar sitting directly below my header/nav and an image. As users scroll I don't want the call to action to come all the way up to the top of the page. I want it to stay in relatively the same place. I want to fill the void left by the header, nav, and image to be filled by more text.

When the users approaches the bottom of the page the footer comes up and will push everything off the top as necessary.

Not sure this is even making sense so I made an image of what the screen would look like as the user scrolls. I don't have the reputation to post it, so it's over on imgur. [Check it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6v29.jpg)

If you have any idea for how to pull this off I would very much appreciate any insight you might be able to provide. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with css and the position fixed attribute. then set the top and right to be the distance you want it from the top and right side of the browser window.

```
    .stickySideBar
    {
    position:fixed;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    right:10px;
    top:200px;
    }
```